# Prevent In-Call Status Bar from Affecting View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to prevent the in-call status bar from affecting my app's views?

I would like the in-call status bar to ideally simply appear on top of my view and not affect its frame (neither by changing the height nor by changing the origin and pushing the view down).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the best solution I was able to find for this is to manually change the main view's frame to start at the origin and have the size of the entire screen (both width and height). That way, you receive the same effect as you would if you were to use a navigation controller for example, where the view remains in place and the in-call status bar appears to be on top of it (on a different layer, without affecting the app view's display).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit or show an example? What do you mean by "start at the origin"? I have tried setting the root view controller's `self.view`'s `frame` to `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` and `self.autoresizingMask` to `.None`, but its height still changes when the in-call status bar appears.